# Library that can host iOS app document directory as FTP server

Tags: ios, ftp

I have an iOS app with a specific purpose, it creates some files, and allows the user to retrieve these files. I have already implemented iTunes file sharing and AirDrop. But sometimes, it is easier to just host all the files as an FTP server so that it is a lot easier to just copy multiple files off into computer. However, I haven't find any library in iOS that can host files as FTP Server. I did find [DFServer](https://github.com/niklasberglund/DFServer) on GitHub. But it says it is used for debugging only (and when I actually tried it it isn't too stable either).

What is a good FTP server API for iOS that I can use to host some files (they are all in the document directory of my app)? Even better if it supports writing to the directory as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use `urlComponents` to access my ftp server. Here is an example of getting the files and saving them in an array:

```
func getFiles(completionHandler: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: nameOfFTPServer) // i.e. ftp://me.myserver.com
    urlComponents?.user = "username"
    urlComponents?.password = "password"
    let url = urlComponents?.url
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    var myError = 0

    if url != nil {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            //no internet connection
            if data == nil || (data?.isEmpty)! {
                myError = NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable
                completionHandler(myError)
            }
            // If error is nil, everything's all good so get the data
            else if error == nil {
                if let data = data, let result = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii) {
                    let array = result.components(separatedBy: "\n")
                    completionHandler(myError)
                }
            }
            else {
                // everything is not all good, handle the error elsewhere
                print(myError!)
                myError = NSURLErrorTimedOut
                completionHandler(myError)
            }
        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

and my completion handler in another class:

```
getFTPFiles(completionHandler: { done in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch done {
        case 0: // data loaded
        case NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable, NSURLErrorTimedOut: // something went wrong
        default:
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

This gets me an array of filenames that I parse out later to display in a tableView, and then to open a file (I'm opening a PDF into a webView here):

```
func loadPDF(filename: String, folder: String){
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: nameOfServer)
    urlComponents?.user = "username"
    urlComponents?.password = "password"
    urlComponents?.path = "/" + folder + "/" + filename
    let url = urlComponents?.url
    if(url != nil){
        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }
    else{
        webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><p>Check your internet connection</p></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm finding a way to host the files with FTP though... I don't really need to retrieve files using FTP.

Comment: Or, without a library you may be able to achieve this with URLSession.uploadTaskWithRequest (look up documentation for more information)